# How was "ten thousand cents" implemented?

Tags: user-interface, drawing, mechanicalturk

How was [ten thousand cents](http://www.tenthousandcents.com/) implemented?  I am particularly interested in the implementation of the interface that accepted the drawings from the user?  Are there libraries available that facilitate this?

Answer (score 3):

One key ingredient seems to be the [Processing](http://www.processing.org/) library -- this is probably what you are looking for. From their [FAQ](http://www.tenthousandcents.com/top.html#faq):

> How did you put everything together?
>
> We used a few different tools to create everything. The interfaces were
>   done with Flash, the movies with After
>   Affects, most everything else was done
>   with [Processing](http://www.processing.org/), and of course, the
>   eyes and hands of thousands of workers
>   online.